# fusiondirectory and OpenLDAP, adding an attribute

Tags: openldap

I am trying to use OpenLDAP and FusionDirectory. I cannot see an option for an email attribute, which I think should be common. I also cannot see how to add an attribute in fusiondirectory.

Would someone on here give assistance please.

Thanks,
Jesse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'am one of the Author of FusionDirectory and my first answer has been removed saying "it doesnt answer tot the question".

My answer is install the fusiondirectory-plugin-mail and you will be able to add email adresses.

FusionDirectory remove the need to touch and add stuff by hand

Cheers

Comment: I did not remove the comment. I guess it was a moderator? I am not sure exactly how this forum works as far as that goes. I see a lot of "answers" that don't answer the question that aren't removed.

Answer (score 2):

After some effort, I found the correct way to deal with this.

As stated above, one must add the mail plugin. In debian, this is with:

```
sudo apt install fusiondirectory-plugin-mail
sudo apt install fusiondirectory-plugin-mail-schema
```

However, the key point is that the schema must also be installed, as it is likely missing:

```
sudo fusiondirectory-insert-schema -i /etc/ldap/schema/fusiondirectory/mail-fd.schema
```

This will result in the appearance of the mail attribute in the 'mail' tab in the correct spot. Tedious and irritating, but works.

tarek : )

Answer (score 0):

In OpenLDAP you have the attribute type 'mail' (RFC822) which is contained in the core schema. If you have a user who is allowed to browse the config tree (cn=config), you can browse the node cn={0}core,cn=schema,cn=config, where this is defined; you can find the definition here, too: http://zytrax.com/books/ldap/ape/core-schema.html#mail

If you want to use it in an account, you can therefore use object class 'inetOrgPerson' where this attribute is already included.

When it comes to FusionDirectory: From what I understand it only seems to be a frontend for other directory systems, therefore you have the same set as in the underlying directory. This is the documentation wiki I found: https://documentation.fusiondirectory.org/start

Comment: So to be clear: Every node you enter has an object class (e.g. inetOrgPerson). These object classes in turn have attributes associated to them. If you want to include other attributes, you add _auxiliary_ object classes to the node which enhance the other classes. `extensibleObject` let's you choose freely; however I don't know whether FusionDirectory supports this...

Comment: Thank you for your reply.<br/><br/> I actually already have the Object Class in OpenLDAP. If I view the directory in phpLDAPadmin I can see the attribute. but since development on pla has stoped there are too many issues to use it. I actually created the original user objects with ldap-account-manager and I can use that but it also has some shortfalls, at least in the free version. Looking at FusionDirectory I had hoped it would be a clean simple interface for managing OpenLDAP but I have to be able to modify mail attribute. <br/><br/> I will try contacting their mailing lists.